# Append a String to a String in a List

Tags: python, string, list, pandas, append

I am reading an excel table:

[image]

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx', usecols = 'A,B,C')
print(df)
```

Now I want to create a list with every row in the table as string.
In addition I want to add a 'X' at the end of every string in the list:

```
keylist = []
list1, list2, list3 = df['A'].tolist(), df['B'].tolist(), df['C'].tolist()

for i in zip(list1, list2, list3):
    val = map(str, i)
    keylist.append('/'.join(val))
    keylist += 'X'

print(keylist)
```

Everything works except the 'adding a X' part. This results in:

```
['blue/a/a1', 'X', 'blue/a/a2', 'X', ....
```

But what I want is:

```
['blue/a/a1/X', 'blue/a/a2/X',
```

Thanks beforehand.

Comment: keylist is an array, so doing += is the same as adding the the array.  You would want to do something moreso akin to val.

Comment: Did you try `val = map(str, i)
    keylist.append('/'.join(val+'X'))` in your for loop!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think  better is:

```
d = {'A': ['blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'yellow', 
           'yellow', 'green', 'green', 'green'],
     'B': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'f', 'g'], 
     'C': ['a1', 'a2', 'b1', 'c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'd1', 'e1', 'f1', 'f2', 'g1']}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
print (df)
         A  B   C
0     blue  a  a1
1     blue  a  a2
2     blue  b  b1
3      red  c  c1
4      red  c  c2
5      red  c  c3
6   yellow  d  d1
7   yellow  e  e1
8    green  f  f1
9    green  f  f2
10   green  g  g1

keylist = df.apply(lambda x: '/'.join(x), axis=1).add('/X').values.tolist()
print (keylist)

['blue/a/a1/X', 'blue/a/a2/X', 'blue/b/b1/X', 'red/c/c1/X', 'red/c/c2/X', 
 'red/c/c3/X', 'yellow/d/d1/X', 'yellow/e/e1/X', 
 'green/f/f1/X', 'green/f/f2/X', 'green/g/g1/X']
```

Or if only few columns:

```
keylist = (df['A'] + '/' + df['B'] + '/' + df['C'] + '/X').values.tolist()
```

Some **timing**s:

```
#[110000 rows x 3 columns]
df = pd.concat([df] * 10000, ignore_index=True)

In [364]: %%timeit
     ...: (df['A'] + '/' + df['B'] + '/' + df['C'] + '/X').values.tolist()
     ...: 
60.2 ms ± 1.04 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [365]: %%timeit
     ...: df.apply(lambda x: '/'.join(x), axis=1).add('/X').tolist()
     ...: 
2.48 s ± 39.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)


In [366]: %%timeit
     ...: list1, list2, list3 = df['A'].tolist(), df['B'].tolist(), df['C'].tolist()
     ...: for i in zip(list1, list2, list3):
     ...:     val = map(str, i)
     ...:     keylist.append('/'.join(val))
     ...:     keylist[-1] += '/X'
     ...: 
192 ms ± 78.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [367]: %%timeit
     ...: df.iloc[:,0].str.cat([df[c] for c in df.columns[1:]],sep='/').tolist()
     ...: 
61.1 ms ± 540 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [368]: %%timeit
     ...: df.assign(New='X').apply('/'.join,1).tolist()
     ...: 
2.51 s ± 76.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [369]: %%timeit
     ...: ['{0}/{1}/{2}/X'.format(i, j, k) for i, j, k in df.values.tolist()]
74.6 ms ± 2.27 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: join works on an array, doing it your way, will give: `blue/a/a2X`.  if you look at my answer, you can easily augment this by adding it to the `val` array...  so that way JOIN works correctly.

Comment: @Fallenreaper ah, but yours will provide a syntax error because of a stray `.` ;)

Comment: touche. hahahaha

Comment: @Fallenreaper - hmmm, I guess you dont downvote, right?

Comment: Again ? sign ...:-(

Comment: In your code, you are just appending it to the end of the result of apply.  is there a way to append the entry to x before the join, so Zip df with a column of "X" ?

Answer (score 1):

You are doing += do the keylist which adds to that list, you need to do it to the `val` array.

```
for i in zip(list1, list2, list3):
  val = map(str,i)
  val += 'X' # you can combine this and the above if you want to look like:
  #val = map(str, i) + 'X'
  keylist.append("/".join(val))
print(keylist)
```

Comment: why?   val is a map, so when you use join, it recognizes the entry and adds it there?

Comment: Its all good. :) I am just using the variables OP uses, otherwise id have named it something a bit more human readable. :)

Comment: Sorry, I dont check it carefully.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way using a list comprehension with `str.format`:

```
res = ['{0}/{1}/{2}/X'.format(i, j, k) for i, j, k in df.values.tolist()]

# ['blue/a/a1/X', 'blue/a/a2/X', 'blue/b/b1/X', 'red/c/c1/X', ...]
```

There is no need, as in this solution, to split into 3 lists and `zip` them.

Answer (score 1):

Base on `pandas`

```
df.assign(New='X').apply('/'.join,1).tolist()
Out[812]: ['blue/a/a1/X', 'blue/a/a2/X', 'blue/b/b1/X']
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add `/X` to last item in `list` everytime in the loop:

```
for i in zip(list1, list2, list3):
    val = map(str, i)
    keylist.append('/'.join(val))
    keylist[-1] += '/X'

# ['blue/a/a1/X', 'blue/a/a2/X',....]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`cat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.cat.html) string operation to join the columns into a single series with a specified `sep` argument. Then simply convert the new series into a list

```
 df
         A  B   C
0     blue  a  a1
1     blue  a  a2
2     blue  b  b1
3      red  c  c1
4      red  c  c2
5      red  c  c3
6   yellow  d  d1
7   yellow  e  e1
8    green  f  f1
9    green  f  f2
10   green  g  g1
```

---

```
df.iloc[:,0].str.cat([df[c] for c in df.columns[1:]],sep='/').tolist()

['blue/a/a1', 'blue/a/a2', 'blue/b/b1', 'red/c/c1', 'red/c/c2', 'red/c/c3', 'yellow/d/d1', 'yellow/e/e1', 'green/f/f1', 'green/f/f2', 'green/g/g1']
```